# How do I check that a user password is locked?

Tags: ubuntu, security

I used:

```
usermod -L myUser
```

to disable the password for this account.  Assuming that I don't know the password how do I check that it has been disabled.

According to the man page it places ! in the front of the encrypted password, but I don't know how to check that either.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [passwd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd) utility to look at the status of the user's password entry

```
passwd -S user
user LK 2012-11-06 0 99999 7 -1 (Password locked.) (CentOS)
user L 01/22/2013 0 99999 7 -1 (Ubuntu)
```

The **LK** as well as the **(Password Locked)** text indicate a locked password entry on CentOS and **L** indicates a locked password entry on Ubuntu.

You can also use [getent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getent) to read the [shadow](http://linux.die.net/man/5/shadow) database

```
getent shadow user
user:!$6$ic7iX.Q2$q9K5gi5pOb...TJlhAIoKVJfAybADtv80:15650:0:99999:7:::
```

or you can just look at the shadow file yourself

```
grep user /etc/shadow
user:!$6$ic7iX.Q2$q9K5gi5pOb...TJlhAIoKVJfAybADtv80:15650:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: What does the 'K' mean?  No entry in the man page, and it is also not present here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/passwd.1.html.  I also do not get (Password locked) as indicated (just mentioned as a troubleshoot, it really isn't a problem)

Comment: Sorry my mistake I was on a CentOS system when I ran the passwd command and it's obviously different from Ubuntu. On Ubuntu the meaning of L is locked, NP means no password and P indicate a usable password. Use the man command on the Ubuntu box - man passwd and look up -S